# Activation/deactivation custom field picklist value from apex

Tags: apex, unit-test, picklist, deactivate

My question is:

Is it possible to activate/deactivate picklist values via apex code?
If so - how to do it?

EDIT
I need to deactivate custom field picklist value on my custom object. I want use it in unit test.

Comment: This sounds like it may be an X-Y Problem. Deactivating a picklist value sounds like an attempted solution for the real problem you're trying to solve here. Can you go into more detail about what problem you're trying to solve by deactivating picklist values?

Comment: My algorithm is as follows: load object from database -> get picklist value -> if value is active do A -> if value is inactive do B. I want to cover both cases in my unit tests if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable a value from `<apex:selectOptions` you have to use this signature `SelectOption option = new SelectOption(value, label, isDisabled);` where isDisabled is a Boolean that, if true, specifies that the user cannot select the option, but can still view it. [**Document reference**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm)

```
public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('US','US'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('CANADA','Canada',true));
    options.add(new SelectOption('MEXICO','Mexico'));
    return options;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Himanshu, but it was not what I am looking for. :) My question was maybe not clear. I need to deactivate a value in the unit test for my custom field picklist on my custom object. I will edit the question.

Comment: @ŁukaszKojzar That you can't do using apex.

Comment: Are you sure? May you deliver the information source? (e.g. link to the documentation) If so - I will accept the answer. :)

Comment: you want to do it from test class right?

Comment: Yes I want to do it from the test class

Comment: Picklist values can be accessed using tooling api (only active one) and from test class you can't make web callout and get response.
By default, test methods don’t support web service callouts (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm)

Comment: Ok, I see there is no way now to simulate deactivation of the custom field picklist value. I am accepting the answer. Thanks for help.